# Parse and FBv4 Swift share picture

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0, parsefacebookutils

Stuck on posting a picture to FB, using `Facebook SDK v4` and `ParseHelperv4` in Swift.
User is created and logged in with read persimmons and I can get user info like mail name and so on,  as for  `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()` it is always empty so response from `FBSDKSharingDelegate` is always you don`t have permission.... Am I doing something wrong?

```
  let permissions : NSArray = ["publish_actions"]
          PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(PFUser.currentUser(), withPublishPermissions: permissions, block: { (aBool, error) -> Void in

                if aBool && error == nil {

                    let aToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()

                    println(aToken.permissions) -- just for logging and it returns empty not even read permissions

                    let fbPhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto(image: self.topImageView.image, userGenerated: true)

                    let aTest : FBSDKSharePhotoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()

                    aTest.photos = [fbPhoto]

                    FBSDKShareAPI.shareWithContent(aTest, delegate: self)    }

            })
```

and delegate

```
   func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

    println(error.description)        

}
```

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=202 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 202.)" UserInfo=0x16535010
>   {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Share API is not
>   available. [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] must have
>   publish_actions permission.}

I am probably missing a step.... Should I somehow set the fbaccestoken to be linked with pffaceookutils?